# NDK Unable to load library UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk

A small portion of my app is written in C. And it works without any problems on most devices. But I'm getting the following error on `Pixel 7 Pro` devices.

```
Caused by java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/~~9XihzNW7ULPF6yR6-VVj4Q==/com.myapp-mK9ZhQGY7rMRjU2sukTrUA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a/libsecrets.so" not found
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1077)
       at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:998)
       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1661)
       at com.myapp.helpers.NetworkJobs.<clinit>(NetworkJobs.java:51)
       at com.myapp.activities.HomeActivity.sendHomeRequest$lambda-6(HomeActivity.kt:216)
       at com.myapp.activities.HomeActivity.$r8$lambda$izwWA0CLpMSNJbhtYIWozopvfD4()
       at com.myapp.activities.HomeActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.run(:2)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

build.gradle contains,

```
externalNativeBuild {

        // Encapsulates your CMake build configurations.
        cmake {

            // Provides a relative path to your CMake build script.
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build your native library.
# This ensures that a certain set of CMake features is available to
# your build.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.1)

# Specifies a library name, specifies whether the library is STATIC or
# SHARED, and provides relative paths to the source code. You can
# define multiple libraries by adding multiple add_library() commands,
# and CMake builds them for you. When you build your app, Gradle
# automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Specifies the name of the library.
             secrets

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/secrets.c )
```

And this is how I load my native lib,

```
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("secrets");
    }
```

I cannot reproduce this issue as I don't have this particular device. The log indicates that it couldn't find `arm64-v8a/libsecrets.so`. But, I have extracted the app bundle, and the file `arm64-v8a/libsecrets.so` exists.

How can I fix this? any help would be appreciated

Comment: I assume you are publishing the app via Play Store? Do you upload a single APK file to Google or an app bundle?

Comment: I upload an app bundle

Comment: Then Google publishes the app not as single APK but as split APK. The error you got is likely caused by someone sideloading the incomplete app may be only with the base APK which contains the dex code but on the native library. I would ignore this error.

Comment: How does this happen? How can someone open an incomplete app?

Comment: You can simply extract the APK files from an existing device, if the app used for extraction  is older it doesn't know split APK files and thus only extracts the base apk file without the necessary native library apk, the config and the layout apk.